# Filtering documents by type in Cosmos Db

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to fetch documents by specific type. Here's my first attempt based on documentation:

```
var dataStoreStatuses = 
  _documentClient.CreateDocumentQuery<DataStoreStatus>(
                    DocumentService.CollectionUri, new FeedOptions() { 
                      EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true })
                 .ToList();
```

The problem is this request returns even documents that don't comply to DataStoreStatus schema. I guess that's how it's supposed to work as Cosmos Db is schemaless (though documentation says that DataStoreStatus defines `the type of object to query`).

I used to use RavenDb and it stored the type of document, so this kind of queries were really easy to execute. Is there a way to achieve that in Cosmos Db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already mentioned, DocumentDB is schemaless. When the documentation says that "DataStoreStatus defines the type of object to query" then I believe what you are looking at is the documentation of client API. The specific generic type argument is not actually part of query sent to DocumentDB storage, but used as a second step after fetching the documents to help automatically map the returned documents to the types you want. The latter step is purely client side.

So, to my knowledge, **it is by design that you cannot query documents by type with your query.**

**Workaround**

If you need to query documents by type then you need to store such information to the documents themselves. It's quite common to have a property named "type" or such. Then you could do a query:

```
select * from c where c.type = 'DataStoreStatus'
```

Note that your entity type should then also contain that field.